# Trouble creating an sql connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an example of a login page that runs off of sql in which I am trying to customize it to my server.

I'm running into issues with the sql string.

Here is the original (with my table info). This appears to be pulling the username and password from the login control with @user and @password; I think. If not what is it doing? what exactly is @user and @password?

```
string sql = "select count(*) from ResidentUserDatabase where users = @user and passwords = @password";
```

Here is where I hard coded a username and password in. This works and I was able to login just fine. Obvioulsy not useable, but confirms i am connecting to the database and pulling user info

```
string sql = "select count(*) from ResidentUserDatabase where users = 'user' and passwords = 'pass'";
```

Now, here is where i have issues (since the first version doesn't work...). I tried to bypass the @user and @password and am apparently not doing it right.

```
string sql = "select count(*) from ResidentUserDatabase where users = '" + LoginControl.UserName.ToString() + "' and passwords = '" + LoginControl.UserName.ToString() + "'";
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here, or why the example doesnt work.

thanks

Comment: "not doing it right." what  is the error exactly ?

Comment: Worth changin the title of the question. This a "parameterized sql" question, not a "sql connection string" question.

Comment: well. no error really. Unless i can find a sql log. it just rejects the password for some reason. seems as if its not using what I type into the login control.

Comment: because you passed the username value  to password column , the issue here < and passwords = '" + LoginControl.UserName.ToString() >

Comment: Thank you. I feel silly for that. it works seamlessly now, although, that leaves me open to slq injection. I do need to figure out why the parameterized part isn't working.

Comment: glad helps you bro.

Comment: well. iv figured out why the 1st line doesn't work. the password is not hashed in the database. i need to figure out what hash my code is using, pass.Value = Hasher.HashString(password.Trim());, and how to put that in the database.

Comment: I really think that you should stop and better understand the tools you are using (assuming this is for some real project with real users).This sounds like the start of a project that will end up on https://haveibeenpwned.com/ or another name-and-shame list

Comment: Hi. thank you for the help. I do learn by doing and asking questions. Yes it is a real project, however once it is finished I do plan on having a cousin of mine (a top notch professional) look over the code and make sure I didn't do anything stupid.

Comment: if it makes any difference I do have a much better understanding of this topic now.

Answer (score 3):

The `@user` and `@password` are parameters of a "parameterized sql query". What you have created in your 3rd code sample is a real security problem. Google the term "Sql Injection attack". If you are unfamiliar with this kind of security concerns, then I would strongly urge you not to be building the login forms for your application. "Here be dragons"

Comment: ok, that makes sense, but, how do I fix the original. The only things I have changed are my data table names.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few things going bad for you here.

First of all, you should not concatenate strings as this leaves you open to SQL injection. Google it and you will see why.

Second, the @user and @password tokens are parameters of a SQL query. What you want to do is add parameters to whatever object you are using to execute the SQL (e.g. SqlCommand). How to do that in detail is beyond the scope of the question.

Third, your string-concatenating query is using **the same field** for username and password. That is why it doesn't work.